# Add a column for COUNT of foreign key objects

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models --

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    ...

class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
    ...
```

I would like to add a COUNT for the number of videos a user has.

Currently, to get the count of a user, I can do `profile.video_set.count()`.

I would like to have an additional column in the UserProfile model so I can just do `UserProfile.objects.order_by('video_count')`. How would I add this custom row to the model? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do does not follow [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) rules. The way to go is by using an annotation:

```
UserProfile.objects.annotate(video_count=Count('video')).order_by('-video_count')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would rather denormalize your counters, for performance, or any other reason, [django-counter-field](https://github.com/kajic/django-counter-field) lets you easily do that:

```
from django_counter_field import CounterField, CounterMixin, connect_counter

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    video_count = CounterField()
    ...

class Video(CounterMixin, models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile')
    ...

connect_counter('video_count', Video.uploaded_by)
```